# Создание админки для app.config другого приложения

Tags: c#

Имеется приложение "DLAutoCalcService", которое берет свои настройки из app.config, в котором сами настройки лежат в разделе :

```
<userSettings>
    <AutoCalcService.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="RoutesOptimize" serializeAs="String">
            <value>False</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="NotificationGoogleAppId" serializeAs="String">
            <value>someValue0</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="NotificationSender" serializeAs="String">
            <value>someValue1</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="NotificationTitle" serializeAs="String">
            <value>someValue2</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="NotificationMessage" serializeAs="String">
            <value>someValue3</value>
        </setting>
    </AutoCalcService.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
```

Причем, для удобства в самом приложении имеется менеджер сеттингов Settings.settigns, находящийся в разделе Properties

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Требуется: создать админку (другое приложение), которое могло бы править настройки DLAutoCalcService в его файле app.config в разделе .

Мне удалось получить настройки другого приложения и даже секцию  этих настроек вот так:

```
        string otherExePath = @"DLAutoCalcService.exe";
        Configuration otherConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(otherExePath);
        var sectgr = otherConfig.SectionGroups["userSettings"];
        string otherSetting = otherConfig.AppSettings?.Settings["RoutesOptimize"].Value;

        otherConfig.AppSettings?.Settings["RoutesOptimize"].Value = "true";
        otherConfig.Save();
```

Далее я надеюсь программно менять им значения и сохранять весь файл. Однако, настройки из секции  другого приложения не отображаются в коллекции AppSettings (count == 0), а в успешно полученном объекте sectgr я вообще не увидел никаких коллекций настроек. Как мне достучаться, например, до параметра RoutesOptimize?

Comment: Правильный подход: в solution должен быть общий проект для проектов админки и клиентского приложения, в нём должны быть определены настройки - и эти два проекта должны иметь ссылку на этот общий проект.

Comment: К сожалению, архитектура приложения уже очень объемная и делать наследование проектов на уровне архитектуры уже невозможно. Не могли бы вы предложить решение, как десериализовать app.config в виде XML и поправить десериализованный объект руками, и сохранить изменения в тот же файл? Проблемы возникли в том, что app.config не полностью соответствует классическому пониманию XML. Там есть вот такое:   <userSettings>
    <AutoCalcService.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="RoutesOptimize" serializeAs="String"> ... </setting>    - что делать с "<AutoCalcService.Properties.Settings>"?

Comment: Нет, с подобными задачами я не сталкивался.

Comment: Ответ был дан в вопросе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/902883/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-app-config