# Получение настроек другого приложения из app.config

Tags: c#, config

Имеется вот такой файл app.config в приложении "A":

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="AutoCalcService.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="AutoCalcService.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2"/></startup>
<userSettings>
    <AutoCalcService.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="RoutesOptimize" serializeAs="String">
            <value>False</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="NotificationSender" serializeAs="String">
            <value>value1</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="NotificationTitle" serializeAs="String">
            <value>value2</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="NotificationMessage" serializeAs="String">
            <value>value3</value>
        </setting>
    </AutoCalcService.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
<applicationSettings>
    <AutoCalcService.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="NotificationGoogleAppId" serializeAs="String">
            <value>value4</value>
        </setting>
    </AutoCalcService.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

Задача: получить доступ к нему из приложения "Б", которое с ним никак не связано, и позволить приложению "Б" править настройки в секции  приложения "A" (секция  доступна только для чтения) - т.е., сделать админку! Возможности архитектурно вынести app.config в отдельное приложение и "унаследовать" от него и "A", и "Б" - увы, нет.

Мне удалось получить сам Configuration и даже отдельные его секции вот так:

```
string otherExePath = @"DLAutoCalcService.exe";
Configuration otherConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(otherExePath);

var sectgr = otherConfig.SectionGroups["userSettings"];
var sect = sectgr.Sections["AutoCalcService.Properties.Settings"];
```

Объекты sectgr (тип ConfigurationSectionGroup) и sect (тип ConfigurationSection) не null, а в sect даже есть мои настройки, но мне не удается до них "достучаться". В публичных членах sect свойство Settings (которое видно на скриншоте) отсутствует.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пожалуйста, помогите мне продолжить мой код до получения, изменения и сохранения измений на примере настройки "RoutesOptimize".

Comment: Фразу "и позволить приложению "Б" править настройки в секции приложения "A" (секция доступна только для чтения)" - читать как - "и позволить приложению "Б" править настройки в секции "userSetting" приложения "A" (секция "applicationSettings" доступна только для чтения)"

Comment: Пожалуйста, используйте кнопку "править" вместо написания комментариев-исправлений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
var sectgr = otherConfig.SectionGroups["userSettings"];
ClientSettingsSection sect = (ClientSettingsSection)sectgr.Sections["AutoCalcService.Properties.Settings"];

//чтение
var element = sect.Settings.Get("RoutesOptimize").Value.ValueXml;            
textBox1.Text = element.InnerXml;

//запись
element.InnerText = "True";
sect.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
otherConfig.Save();
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Хотя и подобное обращение с настройкой (через xml) выглядит странным, это работает и помогло мне.