# не удается найти указанный файл(config), netstandard library

Tags: c#, .net, config, asp, .net-standard

Есть библиотека netstandard, нужно вытащить значение из config, который сам создал и назвал App.config, но при дебаге выдает ошибку- не удается найти указанный файл[image]

Файл выглядит так

[image]

Как достучаться до файла?

Comment: У библиотеки не может быть своей конфигурации, но она может читать конфигурацию приложения, в котором она запущена (если это .NET Framework, конечно). Попробуйте код отсюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/902883/240512 ,может сработает

Comment: библиотека на netstandard 2.0

Comment: app.config использовался в .NET FW. В .NET Core и .NET Standard используется [Configuration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration)